# I can import function but not class with error "AttributeError: module 'XXXX' has no attribute 'YYYY' "

Tags: python, import, attributeerror

I can't load class I defined in another file.  It is strange behavior that I CAN load function defined in the same file.

XXXX.py

```
def hoge():
    print('hoge')

class YYYY:
    def hoge(self):
        print('hoge')
```

I try to import and run XXXX as follow:

```
import XXXX

XXXX.hoge()
XXXX.YYYY
```

Then, I encountered the error

```
hoge
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-cbd9d0cb0faf> in <module>
      2 XXXX.hoge()
----> 3 XXXX.YYYY

AttributeError: module 'XXXX' has no attribute 'YYYY'
```

I use Python 3.6

Comment: [Welcome to Python 101: Chapter 11 - Classes](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter11_classes.html)

Comment: @CONvid19 - I don't see how that explains the import error. Module XXXX has class YYYY.

Comment: It works for me. You could `print(XXXX.__file__)` to see if there are multiple copies of the module. Or even `print(open(XXXX.__file__).read())` to see if the current version really has YYYY in it.

Comment: print(XXXX.__file__)  outputs the correct path "/root/Work/XXXX.py".  print(open(XXXX.__file__).read()) outputs the correct source code.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem.
This error occurs on jupyter-notebook.
But it works on terminal.
I don't know why this happens on jupyter.